# After angular-cli installation it shows 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[image]

I tried to uninstall, remove cache and install and every thing. But it simply shows as not recognised.

Windows: 8.1 pro

Comment: Have you tried some other command? try ng new yourAppName?

Comment: yeah, i have tried. for those commands also its showing same message

Comment: Try npm cache clean --force. And try npm install.

Comment: Yeah I have done that also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ng.cmd which is probably located at %AppData%\Roaming\npm. Make sure this path is included in your PATH variable.

if this doesn't work, try to run the command directly from node js command prompt (not windows command prompts)